# Is there a way to configure the Samsung keyboard quick punctuation pop-up to close after I choose a symbol?

Tags: samsung, keyboard

The Samsung keyboard has a handy button to the right of the space bar that pops up a window to input basic punctuation symbols like commas, parentheses, exclamation etc. What is annoying about it is it won't close after I choose a symbol so, after I press a key (a comma, for example), I have to press the phone's back button to return to the alphanumeric keyboard. Can this be configured?